# How to restart ESP32 on any exception?

Tags: c++, esp32, espressif

While developing a lot of projects (In Arduino IDE) for ESP32 one common issue I am facing is termination of program execution on unhandled exceptions. There are various exception I get.  For example: `stack canary watchpoint triggered (looptask)`, `invoke_abort`, etc. I have no idea how to handle them, hence I prefer to restart the ESP manually.

Is there any way where I can restart the ESP32 automatically on all unhandled or unfortunate exceptions other than handling the exceptions ?

Comment: I know little of the ESP32's internals, but would using the watchdog timer work for this? Or  maybe changing the panic routine so that it resets the MCU?

Comment: @ocrdu hi . can u guide me with sample code for changing the panic routine so that it resets the MCU.

Comment: No, sorry, I have never done that on an ESP32. Sounds googlable, though. Watchdog not an option?

Comment: i have disabled watchdog as it is giving issues in my code flow.

Comment: it should reboot  whenever something blows up, I never see one just crashed out, so you must have changed something. don't disable the watchdog, fix the issues instead.

Comment: I have problems with the ESP8266 running for days then it would stop communicating with the I2C bus. My solution was to monitor a pin toggling on one of the port expanders and if it failed it would power down the whole system then restart it by killing power then turning it back on. Since my variables did not change very often I keep them in NVM. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Gil i had i2c issues too, but calling Wire.begin() again fixed it w/o a reboot.

Comment: Well, why not correct your application to never throw exceptions? That would be the only serious way to solve the issue. (Exceptions prove the rule, for example a remote application with high reliability requirements, but low quality. However, any restart should lead to an enhanced version.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question well, but if what you want to do is reset MCU programmatically, watchdog is good solution.
The orther way is connect IO port and reset port by using wire, and send a signal(send LOW or HIGH voltage to reset port) to reset port.

Or use asm code.

Comment: Hi. 
watchdog is not only getting triggered.